# Why not checking if template file really exists in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF 2.2.5 `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render` method there is an `if` statement that checks if template exists in template stack (line 497)

```
$this->__file = $this->resolver($this->__template);
if (!$this->__file) {
    throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
        '%s: Unable to render template "%s"; resolver could not resolve to a file',
        __METHOD__,
        $this->__template
    ));
}
try {
    ob_start();
    include $this->__file;
    $this->__content = ob_get_clean();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    ob_end_clean();
    throw $ex;
}
```

But it doesn't check if file really exists in file system. Which means that subsequent `try { ... } catch(\Exception $ex) {...}` block is useless, because `include $this->__file;` is uncatchable. So when I test my controllers I always get 200 response even if template file is missing and there is nothing but exception call stack on the screen. Shouldn't that `if (!$this->__file) { ... }` be rewritten to `if (!is_file($this->__file)) { ... }`?

Comment: Why are you asking instead of trying? Also, email ZF developers, this isn't something for StackOverflow as you clearly have a proper vision of what's wrong.

Comment: Well there could be logical or performance concerns, I wasn't 100% sure there is something wrong..was asking out of curiosity

Comment: I doubt that you can find out why ZF developer(s) decided to do that by asking here, but it's obvious that you determined it's not doing what you expect and the test confirmed that. Why don't you trust your judgement? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's up to the resolver to perform these checks. See the following code taken from `Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack`:

```
    foreach ($this->paths as $path) {
        $file = new SplFileInfo($path . $name);
        if ($file->isReadable()) {
            // Found! Return it.
            if (($filePath = $file->getRealPath()) === false && substr($path, 0, 7) === 'phar://') {
                // Do not try to expand phar paths (realpath + phars == fail)
                $filePath = $path . $name;
                if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($this->useStreamWrapper()) {
                // If using a stream wrapper, prepend the spec to the path
                $filePath = 'zend.view://' . $filePath;
            }
            return $filePath;
        }
    }
```

Also note that `include` accepts more than `is_file` checks for. For instance, `include` also accepts [stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. But layouts for some reason are not passing this check. So if I rename/remove layout folder/file I'm getting not catchable warning